# How do I return procedure to savepoints/rollback from a C# application?

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql, npgsql

I am making GUI for postgresql DB using winforms in VS for my university project. As one of my tasks I need to make a stored sql procedure which can be rollback-ed or savepoint-ed AND I need to launch it from my C# application.

So (as i see it) it should work more or less like this:
I have two involved tables: documents and products. DB made for accounting of products. So when a new dispatch is needed:

1. I pass company name from my application and DBMS writes it (as temp data)
2. I pass product name, posgresql checks if a company produces such products (first data integrity condition) and if it is - creates a savepoint in procedure and writes it as temp data or if it's not - rollbackes the transaction.
3. I pass amount of products, posgresql checks if there are enough such products in stock (it satisfies second data integrity condition) and if it is - writes it to db and commits the transaction or if it's not - goes to previously created savepoint. I made a schema: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQ6WN.png)

The problem is - I need somehow to get results to my c# gui of step 2 and 3 so I can decide what to do, furthermore I don't understand how can I resend parameters to my procedure if step-3 check failes.

Here I have approximate procedure's code but I didn't even had chance to check it due to the problems above.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE mydb_schema.insert_doc(
    inserted_id integer, inserted_comp integer, inserted_type bool, inserted_date date, -- step 1 vars
    inserted_prod integer, -- step 2 vars
    inserted_amount integer -- step 3 vars             
)
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $$
DECLARE
BEGIN
    --step 1
    INSERT INTO mydb_schema.my_docs (doc_id, comp_id, in_doc, doc_date)
    VALUES (inserted_id, inserted_comp, inserted_type, inserted_date);
    --step 2
    if (inserted_prod IN (SELECT prod_id FROM mydb_schema.products WHERE comp_id = inserted_comp)) THEN
        INSERT INTO mydb_schema.my_docs (prod_id) VALUES (inserted_prod);
    else
        ROLLBACK;
    END IF;
    -- SAVEPOINT check_amount;  
    BEGIN
        --step 3
        if(inserted_amount >    (SELECT amount FROM mydb_schema.products WHERE comp_id = inserted_comp
                                AND prod_id = inserted_prod)) THEN 
            RAISE EXCEPTION USING errcode = 'WRONG';
        END IF;
    EXCEPTION 
        WHEN SQLSTATE 'WRONG' THEN ROLLBACK;
    END;
    INSERT INTO mydb_schema.my_docs (amount) VALUES (inserted_amount);
END;
$$;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap your code in "transaction" statements.

You seem to have the rollback logic already so it should be very easy for you to do.

Comment: And how do I enter new paraments (new amount to specify) from c# app if my transaction was rolledback to savepoint?

Comment: Well, that depends on your C# code? I can't tell from your SQL code here. 
You would likely need to return a result like "-1" if it rolled back, and then on a -1 status, you would build some sort of handler/repository logic on that result?

Comment: I don't really get what is actually happening to my transaction when it's rolling back to savepoint. Can I somehow continue it with new parametrs - is it waiting for my actions or is it stopped (with saving all results that were done before savepoint)?
If I can't - creating another funtion (enter_amount) just for entering "amount", adjusting this sql prodecure's code with it and executing from c# app enter_amount (in a loop till it completed sucessfully) if I i get report of rolling back to savepoint so i will always get correct amount in my DB seems like a good idea?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/tutorial-transactions.html